# System.Net.FtpWebRequest GetDateTimestamp call dies

Tags: c#, ftpwebrequest

Following test works...

```
  public void test1()
  {
     string server="ftp://myserver.com/dev";
     string userName="myusername";
     string password="mypassword";

     FtpWebRequest req = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create( server );
     req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential( userName, password );
     req.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;
     req.Timeout = 30000;
     req.UseBinary = false;
     req.EnableSsl = false;
     req.UsePassive = false;
     req.KeepAlive = true;

     using( FtpWebResponse resp = (FtpWebResponse)req.GetResponse() )
     {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
        {
           string fileRecord = sr.ReadLine();
           while (fileRecord != null)
           {
              Console.WriteLine( fileRecord );
              fileRecord = sr.ReadLine();
           }
        }
     }
  }
```

While the following test fails...

```
  public void test2()
  {
     string server="ftp://myserver.com/dev";
     string userName="myusername";
     string password="mypassword";

     FtpWebRequest req = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create( server );
     req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential( userName, password );
     req.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetDateTimestamp;
     req.Timeout = 30000;
     req.UseBinary = false;
     req.EnableSsl = false;
     req.UsePassive = false;
     req.KeepAlive = true;

     using( FtpWebResponse resp = (FtpWebResponse)req.GetResponse() )
     {
        using( StreamReader sr = new StreamReader( resp.GetResponseStream() ) )
        {
           Console.WriteLine( resp.LastModified );
        }
     }
  }
```

with error message:

Test method test2 threw exception:  System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access).

UPDATE: I tried with another ftp site (unix) that uses the default port#, so the url is "ftp://myserver.com/dev" - and the GetDateTimestamp() still dies with the same error.

I have updated the subject line and the body of the question to reflect my query properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add more information.

Guess so far: You are trying to

- a) Do a ls on the FTP server (works)
- b) Get at timestamp from the FTP
  server (doesn't work)

Since everything else seems the same (address etc) I assume that both look at the same data. I would imagine that an `ls` just works when you're connected. But what timestamp are you trying to get there? The documentation for [WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetDateTimestamp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequestmethods.ftp.getdatetimestamp.aspx) says

> Represents the FTP MDTM protocol
>   method that is used to retrieve the
>   date-time stamp **from a file** on an FTP
>   server.

(Emphasis by me)

Which file? As far as I can see you are only specifying a folder (not sure if that works)? Did you try this with "ftp://myserver.com/dev/text.txt"?

Comment: @Benjamin - that may very well be the problem. Let me see what happens when the target is a file. In that case, I'll have to switch my code to infer the dat time for a forlder differently.

Comment: @Benjamin - that is exactly what was happening. It works great with a file. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the URI in the 2 examples are the same, your test cases don't match the description of the problem. Can you be more specific?

(In general its easiest to add have a single snippet of example code with the one or two lines that are breaking highlighted.)